# Why is SIB connection closed? (Websphere Service Integration Bus)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, websphere

I have a Message Driven Bean (MDB) deployed on WebSphere 7.0.0.21 which sends JMS messages on a SIB (Service Integration bus) queue.

The JMS resources are created:

```
@Resource(name = CONN_FACTORY, mappedName = CONN_FACTORY)
private QueueConnectionFactory connFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
  queueConnection = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
  queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  responseQueueSender = queueSession.createSender(getResponseQueue());
}
```

And destroyed:

```
@PreDestroy
public void preDestroy() {
  responseQueueSender.close();
  queueSession.close();
  queueConnection.close();
}
```

Sending like this:

```
TextMessage responseMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage("message");
responseQueueSender.send(responseMessage, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, expirationTime);
queueSession.commit();
```

I have about 20 instances of my MDB. When I generate a lot of incoming messages to the MDB, problems arise. I got the following error:

```
CWSIA0053E: An exception was received during the call to the method JmsSessionImpl.getTransaction (#1): javax.resource.spi.IllegalStateException: CWSJR1121E: An internal error has occurred. During the call to the method getManagedConnection the exception javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: CWSJR1028E: An internal error has occurred. The exception com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.exceptions.SIMPConnectionUnavailableException: CWSIK0022E: The connection is closed to messaging engine seit3022Node01.server1-Payment and cannot be used. was received in method createManagedConnection. was thrown..
```

If I increase the Queue connection factory's connection pool size a lot, the error occurs more seldom but it still exists. If I lower the pool size the error occurs very often.

How can the connection be closed? If I have a connection pool size greater than the number of concurrent MDB:s, how can a connection be closed?

There are various properties of the connection pool, but I can't find any regarding closing connections in use... And my code definitely does not close any connection (except in `@PreDestroy`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what causes the `SIMPConnectionUnavailableException` here, but the way you manage the connection in your MDB is not correct anyway. You should move the code in the `postConstruct` and `preDestroy` methods to `onMessage` method and not attempt to reuse the same connection. This is especially important if you want to ensure that the MDB has correct transactional behavior. Note that since the connection factory does connection pooling, requesting a connection per received message doesn't cause overhead.

Comment: According to Oracle's Java EE tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgl.html) both ways of managing resources (in onMessage() or the way I described above) are correct. I tried managing resources in onMessage() and it works without errors, but performance is actually significantly lower! (About 50% longer time consuming 1000 messages including business logic.)